# Online free bug tracking tools?

Tags: test-management, defect-tracking

I need to share some Bugs and Test cases with someone. Is there any more professional way of doing that rather sending it over MS Excel?
I'm looking for some free cloud based test management tool.
Previously I used `demo.testlink.com`, but unfortunately now it is not there.

Comment: If you just want to share the text of some test cases, Google Docs would be more convenient than Excel.

Comment: One of my favorites is using GitHub Issues. It's a bug tracking tool you get for free (public) with each repo you create.

Comment: Do you want it host yourself (I would prefer Trac) or do you need free hosting?

Comment: Why this topic has "-1" rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bug tracking there are multiple tools to use :

- [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/) - up to 5 users
- One of the most famous tools is bugzilla, you can reach [Bugheaven](http://www.bugheaven.com/) for free use
- Check AIVEO, I think they offer free use for a maximum of 3 users

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have private issues, [Trello](http://trello.com) is simple and fast to share and keep track of things.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of free bug tracking tools in the market. You have to do some research and see which one's fits your criteria.

1. **Redmine** - This has a simple UI but is very powerful with it's features and plugins - the Gnatt Chart being one of the most popular features.
2. **Mantis** - It is built in PHP. The “My View” display in MantisBT shows unassigned bug tickets, a project timeline (similar to an activity feed) and lists recently modified and resolved tickets.
3. **Pivotal Tracker** - Pivotal is free for up to 3 users. If you want to scale up, then you need to pay for more users.
4. **YouTrack** - This is another bug management tool, which has been developed by JetBrains. It is similar to Pivotal, in the scene that it is free for small teams ( free up to 10 users and 5GB storage). If you want to scale up, then you need to pay.

You can also get a list of Open Source Bug Management tools [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/bug-tracking-system)

Answer (score 1):

There are some great + free bug tracking tools out there. I recommend to check out the following open source solutions:

- **Redmine**
- **trac**
- **WebIssues**

There's a full comparison of free open-source bug tracking tools in [this article](https://usersnap.com/blog/open-source-bug-tracking/).

Answer (score 1):

One of the most interesting systems I had come across is [XStudio](http://www.xqual.com/products/xstudio.html). They offer a community version, which allows up to 200 tests to be entered. It also allows you to document your defects, requirements, test cases, and test results. I highly recommend it. I am hoping that at my workplace we will be using this system eventually.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Backlog](http://backlog.com) - a bug tracking tool that's free for up to 10 users. The tool works in a browser, you set up a project and add the bugs as issues in that project, and notify the users that you select. They can add comments etc. and so can you - so there's a thread of comments for the record and track resolution progress. Users you notify will need to be added to your account, and it's free to use for up to 10 users.

Comment: Please edit your answer to give more information about Backlog, particularly how this would help the OP more than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are tools that do both (bug management and test management), you will find that most of the more popular test management tools choose to integrate with bug-tracking software. Therefore allowing each tool to focus on what they do best.

Some of the more modern issue tracking tools to consider are:

- [Trello](https://trello.com) - Great if all you want is an easy-to-use free tool to track bugs.
- [Linear](https://linear.app/) - Specifically for issue tracking and they have their own app.
- [ClickUp](https://clickup.com/), [monday.com](https://monday.com/) or [asana](https://asana.com/) - Modern tools that have more project management functionality, but allow easy tracking of issues.

If none of these tools meat your needs, then here's a list of additional [defect management tools](https://blog.testlodge.com/defect-management-tools-list/).